# I need some help regarding definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is a non-negative definite matrix a positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. If $A$ is positive definite, then $\forall \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, If $\vec{x} \neq \vec{0}$, then $\vec{x}^TA\vec{x} > 0$.

On the other hand, $A$ being non-negative definite means that $\forall \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\vec{x}^TA\vec{x} \ge 0$.

The distinction is the $\ge$ vs the $>$. An example of a matrix that is non-negative definite but not positive definite is
[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)]

Note, however, that if $A$ is positive definite, $A$ is also non-negative definite.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the same. Take $A=0$ for example.